# How to pass raw json data in android retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I have a post method in API, I want to post the data to the API as JSON raw. When I am testing from postman it is working correctly. From my its getting different response.

```
Map<String, String> paramObject = new HashMap<>();
paramObject.put("username", "jino");
paramObject.put("password", "12345");
paramObject.put("confirmpassword", "12345");
paramObject.put("email", "jino@gmail.com");
paramObject.put("phone", "1234567898");
UserService service = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(UserService.class);
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.signUp(paramObject);
```

Service

```
@POST("addnewuser.php")
Call<ResponseBody> signUp(@Body Map<String, String> body);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass JsonObject instead of `Map`:

```
public interface RetrofitService {
    @POST("addnewuser.php")
    Call<ResponseBody> signUp(@Body JsonObject body);
}
```

Create it as following:

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("username", "jino");
jsonObject.addProperty("password", "12345");
jsonObject.addProperty("confirmpassword", "12345");
jsonObject.addProperty("email", "jino@gmail.com");
jsonObject.addProperty("phone", "1234567898");
```

And call your `Retrofit` service:

```
Call<ResponseBody> call = service.signUp(jsonObject);
```